# Need to find solutions to these equations

Tags: equation-solving

Find the solutions to the general cubic a x^3 +b x^2+c x +d=0 and the solutions to the general quartic a x^4+b x^3+c x^2+d x+e=0.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE. Are you sure you are posting on the right site? There is nothing in your question making it clear that it is concerned with Mathematica software.

Answer (score 2):

```
Solve[x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e == 0, x]
```

```
Solve[x^4 + 2x^3 + 3 x^2 + 4 x + 5 == 0, x]// ToRadicals
```